# Geodesic question

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, information-geometry

Let $\mathcal{P}:=\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X})$ be the $n$-dimensional manifold of all (strictly positive) probability distributions on
$\mathcal{X}=\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$. Each $p=(p(x_0),\dots,p(x_n))\in \mathcal{P}$ is thought of a point in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{X}}$.

Let $\mathcal{P}=\{p_{\xi}\}$ be a parameterization. An affine connection $\nabla^{(e)}$, called $e$-connection, is defined on $\mathcal{P}$, given by the Christoffel symbols
\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma_{ij,k} & := & \sum_x\partial_i(\partial_j\log p_{\xi}(x))\cdot \partial_k p_{\xi}(x).
\end{eqnarray}
 According to Wikipedia: In the presence of an affine connection, a geodesic is defined to be a curve whose tangent vectors remain parallel if they are transported along it.

Now suppose that $\gamma(t)$ is a geodesic on $\mathcal{P}$, connecting two points $p$ and $q$. Then, does the above statement mean $$\frac{d}{dt}(\log\gamma(t))=\alpha(t)\cdot\textbf{v},$$
where $\alpha(t)$ is scalar depends on $t$ and $\textbf{v}$ is a fixed vector?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to the question.  If $\gamma(t)$ lives on a manifold, what do you mean by $\text{log}(\gamma(t))$

Comment: That is how is log defined.  Are you just considering manifolds that are open subsets of $R^n$ ?

Comment: @aginensky $\mathcal{P}$ is an open set of the affine subspace $\{A\in R^{n+1}:\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}A(x)=1\}$ of $R^{n+1}$. $\gamma(t)$ lives in $\mathcal{P}$. So, for each $t$, $\gamma(t)$ is a probability distribution (i.e., a point in $R^{n+1}$) and then $\log$ is applied componentwise.